# Apache2 SetEnv For Multiple VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04, environment-variables

I am looking to use a single declaration of a `SetEnv` var in my `apache2.conf` file & have that variable used by all the virtualhosts

I currently have virtualhost-specific vars set up, but would really prefer something more modular like this

Wondering what is the best way to achieve this?